# Как трактовать подобный синтаксис импортирования в Python\Django: < from django.conf.urls import url >?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Я только осваиваю стек Python-Django и сложилось так, что приходится делать это кавалерийским наскоком. Понимаю, что подключается модуль. Через точку можно обратиться к содержимому и далее, далее ... Т.е. это тема из ООП: обращаемся к классу, далее - к его ключу со значением, к методу ... всё через точку.
Приведённый код - из файла mysite/urls.py.
Я пытался найти вот эти вот подключаемые по умолчанию модули (

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
```

) но почему-то не могу.
Пока что прохожу простенький курс, но вот сталкиваюсь с поверхностностью инфы. Смотрел по модулям в pythonworld.ru, так там всё на уровне "подключаем модуль math".

[Здесь копия локальной директории проекта](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5C1lq-Zgx2hcTF2ZXhpSHdPckE)

Comment: Что-то я вопроса так и не понял. Если вы хотите найти, где лежат `url` и `admin`, то они лежат в том каталоге, куда вы установили django

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять что подключается, принципиально. Этот код - по умолчанию, но я пытаюсь в нём разобраться, мне ведь те же приёмы использовать.

Comment: В первом импорте вытаскивается [функция url из модуля urls](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/__init__.py), во втором импорте вытаскивается [подмодуль admin из модуля contrib](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin)

Comment: Подмодуль? А это что за зверь?

Comment: Модуль внутри модуля, ничего особенного. Модулем может быть любой каталог с файлом `__init__.py` (иногда его называют пакетом)